# Join multicast group with java

Tags: java

How to notify other computers with multicast to join a specific group id with pure java?

Example:

1)Pc1 --> multicast ipv6 -> join to group id: ...

2)All windows pc listening on broadcast address in ipv6 change to the group id ...

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the [MulticastSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) class? It even contains sample code.

Comment: I don't understand. Pc1 sends a message to a multicast group, and others pcs listen it on broadcast? How's that possible?

Comment: In here: http://www.sixscape.com/joomla/sixscape/index.php/technical-backgrounders/tcp-ip/ip-the-internet-protocol/ipv6-internet-protocol-version-6/ipv6-multicast-addresses in the middle it says " Every IPv6 host (a node that does not do packet forwarding) automatically joins the following groups: [...]". I need to say to other computers in network, (with java) to join the group i want.